# Outlook Export Distribution Lists + items included with C#

Tags: c#, outlook, export

I'm creating a code which exports Contacts + Distribution Lists from Outlook to store them in a BDD.

I can export the Contacts with the following code :

```
mapiFolder.Items.Restrict([MessageClass] = \"IPM.Contact\);
```

After it's done, I do the same for Distribution Lists

```
mapiFolder.Items.Restrict("[MessageClass] = \"IPM.DistList\"");
```

I'm parsing my Distribution Lists and store them with the help of the library Redemption this way:

```
foreach (DistListItem distributionListItem in distributionListItems)
                {
                    //use of Redemption to avoid a security message when accessing to contacts list
                    var safeList = new SafeDistList();

                    safeList.Item = distributionListItem;

                    var safeDistListExtended = new SafeDistListExtended(safeList, distributionListItem.DLName);
```

Once I've "read" all the distribution lists, it's time to insert them in BDD.

First thing: check what's included in each distribution list, I mean, Contacts or/and Distributions lists which themselves can contain other Contacts or/and Distributions list and so on.

```
var recipients = new List<SafeRecipient>();

        for (int counterMember = 1; counterMember <= pSafeDistListExtended.DistList.MemberCount; counterMember++)
        {
            SafeRecipient safeRecipient = pSafeDistListExtended.DistList.GetMember(counterMember);

            safeRecipient.Resolve();

            if (safeRecipient.Resolved)
            {
                recipients.Add(safeRecipient);                                
            }
        }
```

my problem is there, I can get the ContactItems included in my distribution list but I can not get the distribution lists included but only their names.

What I'd like is when I'm parsing the loop "GetMember", I cast in an object "Distribution List" whether it's actually a Distribution List included in another one.

Because right now, I see all the objects included in a Distribution List as an object of a same type.

Someone would have an idea how to do it ??

Just to let you know that the way to get the Contacts with the loop

```
Member.Count
```

and `GetMember(x)`

is far away to be ideal, because we could expect an object hierarchy. A distribution List containing either ContactItems +/or Distributions Lists and so on...

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you might want to switch to the RDO family of objects instead of using OOM + Safe*Item objects: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm
Secondly, `RDODistListItem.GetMembers` will return `RDOAddressEntries`. For each `RDOAddressEntry` object in that collection, recursively process each object - distribution lists will in turn expose their members through the `RDOAddressEntry.Members` collection.